# Hide home as up indicator on Android actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to custom our home as up indicator on our Android ActionBar. I have change the icon and padding using theme style.

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/fb_back</item>
```

While this make the function

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

become useless. Because in some situation I want to hide the up arrow icon. However calling this leaves large space left of the home button. I am working on sdk 16, so I cannot dynamically set the homeAsUp indicator using

```
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator
```

Some one know a better solution to do this?

Comment: Don't you know how to do it?